# How to connect from iOS to a local Google App Engine Endpoint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-endpoints

We have an iOS app that needs to connect to a Google App Engine Endpoint.
The connection is done via Objective-C Google Api and the generated API from the App Engine Endpoint discovery file.

The code works well connecting to the appspot.com deployed application but we cannot manage to make a call to the local App Engine server running the same application.

The code to call the endpoint is (Swift code):

```
let myService =  GTLServiceMyService()
self.myService.authorizer = GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.authForGoogleFromKeychainForName(kKeychainItemName,
        clientID: kClientID,
        clientSecret: kClientSecret)
let query = GTLQueryMyService.queryForContentsGetContents() as GTLQueryMyService
query.orderBy = "NAME"
self.myService.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: { (ticket: GTLServiceTicket!, object: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    // Process the response
})
```

As I said the code is working but only with the appspot.com server, how to connect to the local server api?

```
http://localhost:8080/_ah/api
```

Also a Objective-C example is good for us.

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to help anyone with the same problem the solution is to put this code after setting the `authorizer` object on `myService` (using Swift):

```
    (self.myService.authorizer as GTMOAuth2Authentication).shouldAuthorizeAllRequests = true
    self.myService.retryEnabled = true
    self.myService.fetcherService.allowLocalhostRequest = true
    self.myService.rpcURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/rpc?prettyPrint=false")
    self.myService.apiVersion = "v1"
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding your question "As I said the code is working but only with the appspot.com server, how to connect to the local server api? "

Remember localhost on your phone refers to the phone's localhost which is different from your development machine's localhost.  Localhost resolves to the IP address 127.0.0.1 (generally).  So to connect to a locally running app engine instance you'll need to use that computer's IP address on your local network.